# PDO query returns true but ->fetch() returns error

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to use PDO to select info from my database. Everything up until the `->prepare()->execute()` method works fine. I get a boolean true response when dumping the response.

But as soon as I use `->fetchAll()` I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean in ....

I'm not sure why this is happening. I should be receiving a single row in the results. Code below:

```
    $host = 'localhost';
    $db   = 'database';
    $user = 'useername';
    $pass = 'password';
    $charset = 'utf8mb4';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
    $connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM gen_dealers WHERE dealer = ?';
    $result = $connection->prepare($query)->execute(['General Motors']);

    echo $result; // returns 1

    $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE); // returns the Fatal error mentioned above
```

Comment: You just said that `execute` returns `true`. How will `$result` which is `true` have a `fetchAll` method?

Comment: You should consider using one of the many [PDO wrappers](https://www.google.com/search?q=pdo+wrapper&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS745US745&oq=pdo+wrapper&aqs=chrome.0.35i39j69i61j69i60l2j0l2.943j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), I personally suggest the one I wrote called [GrumpyPDO](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/GrumpyPDO) where your entire code (including db setup) could be replaced with 3 lines. One line to include the class, one line to define your `$db` variable, and one line for the actual query. `$result = $db->all('SELECT * FROM gen_dealers WHERE dealer = ?', ['General Motors']);`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton interesting. So I assume your wrapper can handle any query thrown at it...even more complex one's?

Comment: @VenomRush I've been using it in all my projects and haven't found anything that it can't do. It should be able to do anything that native PDO can do. If you find that it can't do something, feel free to post an issue in Github and I'll try to find a solution to the prooblem.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @VenomRush I just did a small update on the class, if you are already using it this update will not break your existing code so I suggest you use the latest version. I also did a huge overhaul on the entire documentation, so you could check that out too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't chain prepare.  Prepare returns the PDOStatement object which you're supposed to be fetching from and execute returns a boolean based on the success of the execution of that statement.

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
$result = $stmt->execute(['General Motors']);
if ($result) { 
    $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);
}
```

Comment: There is no need to check the return value of execute. It should never be false if `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` is On.

Comment: Likely true @Dharman if you can rely on error exception mode never changing.  But since by definition, execute does return a bool, it's best practice to still check for the result.

Comment: so does `prepare` & `fetchAll` and you never check that.

Comment: @Dharman that's true... this was just an example based on the given code.  In a real life example, you would check that you got a real PDOStatement back and you would actually be using the results..